# Enum в C++ и его переназвание

Tags: c++, enum

Здарствуйте, я недавно изучаю С++ и наткнулся на некую запись

```
enum eDirection {...};
eDirection dir;
```

а затем уже как присваивали значение dir, глупый конечно вопрос, но это означает просто, что для перечисления сделали другое имя dir, или же это нужно для того, чтобы самолично менять значение перечесления? Извините , если действительно глупый вопрос, но я не понимаю

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем понял, что именно вызывает смущение:

- `enum eDirection {...};` —  это определение нового *перечислимого типа* с именем `eDirection`.
- `eDirection dir;` — это определение переменной типа `eDirection` с именем `dir`.
- Далее этой переменной, по видимому, присваиваются какие-то значения.

Comment: Добавьте рекомендацию про `enum class`.

Comment: @MrBin, не считаю их использование строго обязательным... по мне, это лишь синтаксический сахар: иногда смотрятся лучше, иногда — хуже... а ошибки от которых они защищают в дефолтных предупреждениях компиляторов...